# How to find checkbox is checked or unchecked using XPath in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Not able to find whether checkbox is check or not? throwing exception.

I am using this XPath for checkbox:

```
.//*@id='row_SelectedProductURLIds0']//input[@id='actualcheckbox_SelectedProductURLIds' and @type='checkbox']
```

Image:

[image]

Code:

```
    public bool VerifyCheckbox(By by, String expected)
    {
        bool isPresence = false;
        WaitUntilElementIsPresent(by);
        //string value = GetText(by);
        //bool actual = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
        bool expect = Convert.ToBoolean(expected);
        // actual = expect ? isPresence = true : isPresence = false;
        isPresence = Driver.FindElement(by).Selected;
        Assert.AreEqual(expect, isPresence);
        if (isPresence != expect)
        {
            isPresence = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isPresence = true;
        }

        return isPresence;

    }
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Your `xpath` seems to be wrong use this `//input[@id='actualcheckbox_SelectedProductURLIds' and @type='checkbox']`..

Comment: you can use .isSelected() method to verify whether the checkbox is selected or not.

Comment: you can use this, assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("your-xpath").getAttribute("value"), "off");. on/off will work for check and uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what all you are trying to accomplish but I've simplified it.

```
public bool VerifyCheckbox(By by, bool expected)
{
    bool actual = Driver.FindElement(by).Selected;
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    return (expected == actual);
}
```

I don't guess I understand why you need to Assert if they are equal *AND* return if they are equal. It seems redundant. It would be better to get rid of this whole function and just do the below.

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, Driver.FindElement(By.Id("actualcheckbox_SelectedProductURLIds")).Selected);
```